# How to find differences over one file to another in Linux

Tags: linux, bash

File1.txt

```
Mango
Oranges
```

File2.txt

```
Mango
Apple
```

I want to find differences over one file to the another. I am expecting the output as

```
oranges
```

I want to compare file1 different from file2. What exists in file1 but not in file2.
I have used `diff file1.txt file2.txt` it’s giving me all different values between both files

Comment: Are all the words on a single line in the files?

Comment: No they are not. I will edit the question. Thanks for pointing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `comm`

```sh
comm -23 \
    <(cat File1.txt | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sort -u) \
    <(cat File2.txt | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sort -u)
```

```
oranges
```

Or `awk`

```sh
awk '
    {
        w = tolower($0)
    }
    FNR == NR {
        words[w]++
        next
    }
    w in words {
        delete words[w]
    }
    END {
        for (w in words)
            print w
    }
' File1.txt File2.txt
```

```
oranges
```